# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Color>'

Tags: flutter

I have this working BoxDecoration:

```
BoxDecoration(
    gradient: RadialGradient(
      colors: [Colors.red, tileColorSwitch(store.baskets[index].color]),
  );
```

But when i put it in a constant so I can re-use it, the following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'List< dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List< Color>'

```
kBoxDeco1(context, gradColors) {
  return BoxDecoration(
    gradient: RadialGradient(
      colors: gradColors,
    ),
  );
}

Container(
   decoration: kBoxDeco1(
   context,[Colors.red, tileColorSwitch(store.baskets[index].color)],
),
```

This is my tileColorSwitch method:

```
tileColorSwitch(colorString) {
  switch (colorString) {
    case "grey":
      return Colors.grey;
      break;
    case "yellow":
      return Colors.yellowAccent;
      break;
    case "cyan":
      return Colors.cyanAccent;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely because you've not added the return type to the tileColorSwitch method.

```dart
Color tileColorSwitch(colorString) {
  switch (colorString) {
    case "grey":
      return Colors.grey;
      break;
    case "yellow":
      return Colors.yellowAccent;
      break;
    case "cyan":
      return Colors.cyanAccent;
      break;
    default:
      ......
      break;
  }
}
```

Also note the addition of the default case. Without it the method will likely complain as the method wouldn't always return a Color object

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. However after adding default case, I still get the same error unless I enforce the type as BabC said

Comment: Did you add the return type as Color 'Color tileColorSwitch(colorString)' ?

Comment: oh sorry, yes it works, makes more sense now :D thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the type might help

```
kBoxDeco1(context,List<Color> gradColors) {
  return BoxDecoration(
    gradient: RadialGradient(
      colors: gradColors,
    ),
  );
}
```